# How to split commands to multiple lines nicely in xonsh?

Tags: command-line, shell, xonsh

Consider this command in bash:

```
docker run -d \
    --rm \
    --name postgres-prod \
    --env TZ="Europe/Budapest" \
    --mount type=bind,src=/secure/postgres/prod/data,dst=/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    --mount type=bind,src=/secure/postgres/prod/backup,dst=/backup \
    --mount type=bind,src=/secure/postgres/secrets/postgres_pwd.txt,dst=/etc/postgres_pwd.txt \
    --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE="/etc/postgres_pwd.txt" \
    -p 0.0.0.0:5432:5432 \
    postgres_hun:11
```

I want to split very long commands like the above in xonsh scripts. If I simply use the above script with xonsh then I get this error:

```
./test.xsh                                                                                                                                              
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp, stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xonsh", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 24019, in main
    _failback_to_other_shells(args, err)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 23983, in _failback_to_other_shells
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 24017, in main
    return main_xonsh(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 24060, in main_xonsh
    run_script_with_cache(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 3041, in run_script_with_cache
    ccode = compile_code(filename, code, execer, glb, loc, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 3000, in compile_code
    ccode = execer.compile(code, glbs=glb, locs=loc, mode=mode, filename=filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 23105, in compile
    code = compile(tree, filename, mode)
TypeError: expected Module node, got Expression
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. Backslash can also be used for line continuation in python, I think this should work but it doesn't. Also tried to put the whole thing between parentheses, and also put it inside `$()` but those don't work either.

I came up with this "solution":

```
#!/usr/bin/xonsh

import subprocess

cmd = [
    "docker", "run", "-d", "--rm",
    "--name", "postgres-prod",
    "--env", 'TZ="Europe/Budapest',
    "--mount", "type=bind,src=/secure/postgres/prod/data,dst=/var/lib/postgresql/data",
    "--mount", "type=bind,src=/secure/postgres/prod/backup,dst=/backup",
    "--mount", "type=bind,src=/secure/postgres/secrets/postgres_pwd.txt,dst=/etc/postgres_pwd.txt",
    "--env", "POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/etc/postgres_pwd.txt",
    "-p", "0.0.0.0:5432:5432",
    "postgres_hun:11"
]
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=False)
```

But this looks ugly, hard to read, easy to mistype, clumsy etc.

I have read the xonsh tutorial, also the "bash to xonsh transition" part but there was nothing about splitting long commands into multiple lines.

How can I do this without adding too much syntax noise? Something that is easy to write and read, and easy to use?

Answer (score 0):

Multiline statements split with `\` (like the one in the question) work with `xonsh` `v0.11`.